# Is there a definitive Perl style guide?

Tags: perl

I'm wondering if there's a document or a page which has a style guide for Perl. For example, this is one that I use for C++: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html.

Is there a style guide for Perl that most people use / follow?

Comment: Just of out curiosity, do you know why it got pulled down?

Comment: Install `Perl::Tidy`. It comes with a script, `perltidy` which reformats Perl code. https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Tidy https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Tidy/bin/perltidy

Comment: PS: While you're at it, install `Perl::Critic`. It comes with a script, `perlcritic`, which complains about your Perl code. It follow many of PBP. https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic https://metacpan.org/pod/perlcritic

Comment: “Perl Best Practices” is a great discussion and outline of style issues and considerations. There are a couple dozen which I would call poor (e.g., prefer inside-out objects) and another 50 or so which I would call subjective (never use postfix `unless`). It’s a very good book to read though! Reading the code of top CPAN modules and their tests (ones with many contributors/devs especially) is also a good way to see what community standards look like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's [perldoc perlstyle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) in the standard documentation.

> Regarding aesthetics of code lay out, about the only thing Larry cares strongly about is that the closing curly bracket of a multi-line BLOCK should line up with the keyword that started the construct. Beyond that, he has other preferences that aren't so strong..
>
> .. Larry has his reasons for each of these things, but he doesn't claim that everyone else's mind works the same as his does.

If you install the `Perl::Tidy` module it includes the program/tool `perltidy` that will reformat your code to conform to Larry Wall's preferences as expressed in `perlstyle`.  With the command line parameter `-pbp` it will instead conform to the style preferences Damian Conway expressed in his book `Perl Best Practices`.

Comment: You might also look at: "Perl Best Practices" by Damian Conway.

Comment: Haha. I ordered that book earlier today, actually.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @user2864740.  I couldn't pick anything decent to give the answer more than the link.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Perl Style](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/style/slide-index.html) guide written by [Tom Christiansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist), who is one of the top Perlers out there.

Comment: As a recovering programmer who looked at Perl, many of Tom's suggestions are ant-best-practices as noted in more maintainable languages.  For example, functions named by what the do, instead of what the provide.  That's a mantinabliity nightmare, because if you change the function's contents, you should rename it, forcing a refactoring of the entire codebase (and Perl lacks great refactoring tools)

Comment: @EdwinBuck except he never suggested that. Read again: `Procedure names should reflect what they do; function names should reflect what they return.’

Comment: @DeathkampDrone No, he quoted someone else, bringing perl making conventions up to (I kid you not) 1989.  Perhaps 33 years of improvements in languages and software engineering now recommend better ways.  If you don't believe me, there is this cool thing out there called Hungarian notation (just kidding, run from Hungarian notation).  Reading Clean Code offers this-century points of view on naming, which is why I wrote what I did.  Also, the need to differentiate between functions and procedures disappeared a long time ago, when returning nil from a procedure created the same interface as a fu

Comment: @EdwinBuck Just because Rob Pike wrote that in 1989 doesn't mean it doesn't apply today (and it doesn't mean it applies, either). In fact, the quote agrees with you: "function names should reflect what they return." A procedure is another name for a function without a return value, and is a corner case of a function that shouldn't be named after what it returns (which is nothing). Functions without a return value are called for its side effects, so they should be named after what they do instead.

Comment: Also, Clean Code's naming suggestions focus on OOP and method names, not function names. Whereas Rob Pike's are naming suggestions for imperative code in general. They don't contradict each other.

Comment: You are, of course, free to name stuff how you like; but, I think those you interact with would prefer if you used a naming convention based on modern approaches, like https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-better-name-your-functions-and-variables-e962a4ef335b It is still applicable to C and if you follow it, you run less risk of having to rename your functions during the effort of adding functionally.